# How to retrieve data from radio buttons?

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I have data source (firebase) that contains a list with each item. In flutter, I'm importing the list and populating a custom scrollview with radio buttons using the data as a/b choices. How do I get this dynamic form data for each radio button selection into a variable? or back into my database?

edited: what I'm trying to do is get the value of the radio button selection into a list variable(_pick) with : var _pick =data[i].home; print(_pick);

```
                    new Text("GAME: ${data[i].game} ${data[i].away.toUpperCase()} at ${data[i].home.toUpperCase()} "),

                    RadioListTile<SingleGame>(
                      subtitle: const Text('record 3- 1'),
                      title: new Text("${data[i].home.toUpperCase()}"),
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                      value: SingleGame.$home,
                      groupValue: data[i].selectedValue,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                      onChanged: 
                      (SingleGame value) {
                        setState(() {
                          data[i].selectedValue = SingleGame.$home;
                          var _pick =data[i].home; print(_pick);
                          //var _selectedIndex=_pick;
                          //picksList.add(_pick); 
                        });
                      },

                      selected: data[i].selectedValue == SingleGame.$home,
                    ),
                    ////
                    RadioListTile<SingleGame>(
                      subtitle: const Text('record 3- 1'),
                      title: new Text("${data[i].away.toUpperCase()}"),
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                      value: SingleGame.$away,
                      groupValue: data[i].selectedValue, 
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                      onChanged: (SingleGame value) {
                        setState(() {
                          data[i].selectedValue = SingleGame.$away;
                          var _pick =data[i].away; print(_pick);
                          // _picksList.add(_pick);
                        });
                      },
                      selected: data[i].selectedValue == SingleGame.$away,

                    ),
```

Comment: please can you limit the code only to the part that contains the problem and add a screenshot if you can to understand better what is your problem

Comment: I edited the code snippet to include only radio list button

Comment: ok i understand what you want, you can add an id in the singlegame class so that you save the data in a list of singlegame objects ,and check before adding an object  to the pick list if the object already exists in the list by the id that we added in the singlegame class

Comment: I thought that I was already doing as you describe here:
     enum SingleGame { $game, $home, $away, $selectedValue }

I seem to be missing something.